# Fridge water dispenser not working?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator

We have a Fridgidaire FRS26ZRG but for some reason the water and ice is not working.  I of course pulled the refrigerator out and checked the supply line.  There didn't seem to be any pressure.  I disconnected from the fridge and got a nice flow of water coming in from the supply.  However when I connect it and try using the water, nothing happens.  It makes a sound like it's trying to pump the water through but I don't see the water coming through the line and there doesn't seem to be any pressure once I connect the line back up and turn the water back on.  Is there something obvious here?  I tried holding the water dispenser in for a good 3 minutes and all I could get was a drip.  Is there some other valve that needs opening?  Is it a clog?  Is there a more serious problem?  Thanks for any insight you can offer on this.

Comment: This one is a little hard to diagnose, but I would say you have a clog or a valve not opening. Could be a plugged filter. If you get water from the valve thru the line to the fridge, but nothing past the fridge, then its in the fridge somewhere. I had my fridge out for cleaning once, when it was pushed back in, it kinked the hose and caused the water to not run into it. I assume you have checked for a kink in the hose. Options are to remove the rear panels on the fridge and follow the water line. Disconnect it each step of the way and test until you find the problem area.

Answer (score 1):

A [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&newwindow=1&biw=1360&bih=638&q=Frigidaire%20FRS26ZRG%20no%20water&oq=Frigidaire%20FRS26ZRG%20no%20water&gs_l=serp.3...1739.2680.0.2748.9.6.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.serp..9.0.0.ShErADLrhcc) turns up [several common issues](https://www.repairclinic.com/RepairHelp/How-To-Fix-A-Refrigerator/52-2-626761-/Frigidaire-Refrigerator-water-dispenser-not-working-FRS26ZRG) with that model refrigerator.

The top three most common causes, according to the website are:

1. Frozen water line.
2. Insufficient water pressure.
3. Clogged water filter.

---

### Frozen water line

Sometimes, the water line in your refrigerator can freeze inside the freezer door. This is caused by a combination of poor design *(It's frigidaire, what do you want?)* and having the freezer temperature set too low.

You can check for this by doing the following.

1. Remove the bottom skirting from the refrigerator.
2. Disconnect the coupling on the water line near the floor.
3. With both ends of the water line pointed into a pan/towel/something to catch the water, push the lever for the water dispenser.
4. One of two things should happen. Either you get water pouring into the pan/towel/whatever, or you don't.
5. If you get water pouring out of one end of the tube while you have the water dispenser engaged, then you likely have a frozen water line in the freezer door. Proceed to step 6. If you do not, skip to the next section.
6. Reconnect the coupling and reattach the skirting.
7. Using a hair dryer or heat gun, heat the outside of the freezer door, focusing below the water dispenser for 10 to 15 minutes. Check if water has been restored. Repeat as necessary.

---

### Insufficient pressure

The inlet valves, according to Frigidaire spec sheet, have a minimum operating pressure of 20 PSI. If your house's water pressure is set, or dropped, below that threshold, then the inlet valve will not be able to operate properly.

Check the water pressure at your holding tank to make sure it's above 20 PSI. If it isn't, raise the pressure of your system.

---

### Clogged water filter

As you use it, your water filter will become clogged with sediment and other nasties. As a result, it should be replaced approximately every six months. Generally, the procedure is as follows.

1. Locate the filter housing (usually near the top of the refrigerator compartment.
2. Push the filter body about 1" deeper into the housing, then remove.
3. Push the replacement filter into the housing until unable to go further.

The procedure for your refrigerator may be different. Check your owners manual.