GE fridge ice/water dispenser stopped working
I have a GE fridge/freezer unit and the water dispenser stopped working. However the ice machine is still going, which to me implies that the water intake line splits at some point and somewhere along the way to the door there is a clog. Does anyone know what I should do here? Is there a way to take off the door panel (a quick google search didn't lead me to any instructions but I plan on looking again) or is there another approach I should be taking? I do not see a way of taking the door panel off as there aren't any screws but there are some nubs that possibly cover the screws.



Parts diagram doesn't seem to be much help—don't see a tank or internal tube routing.  IDK what a pro would do, but as a DIYer, I'd try reaming out the water dispenser tube from the business end, using something like a thick weekwhacker line (basically something stiff that'll fit up there).  Press the button to turn it on if you have to, in case you get blocked by a valve.

@Huesmann, thanks for the encouragement. I tried following the instructions for a frozen line found here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/107573/fridge-water-dispenser-not-working. After attempting to unfreeze the line, pushing down on the water dispenser now no longer makes a wooshing impeller sound, so I guess my hair dryer must have melted some piece/lever. At least I am back to where I started, but this is more a word of caution for any future reader for this problem.

Whoops.  Anyway, I find the Parts Dr forum to be pretty helpful on appliance issues.  Maybe you can get some traction there.
